# Is there in any performance difference between defining event in front/admin and global?

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer

I was wondering that what is difference between defining event in frontend/admin and global. I know that we can define events  in admin or frontend and also can be define the same events in global.So is there any performance difference between Frontend/admin and global

thank you

Comment: I guess it would obviously make better/easier for magento to look at when calling an event specifically.

Comment: @AdarshKhatri Yes, i know that but i was wondering what is performance difference between them. How magento look for specific event as i think it check for event, it need to check whole config. Please correct me if i am wrong

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on what your observer does and if it gets dispatched.
If it's heavy, it will have an impact.
You should define events only in the area that you need it.
For example, if you need something to happen when every page loads on frontend and you put it under the `global` area then it will impact the admin also, because it will be dispatched for every admin page also. And you might not need that.
But if, for example, you are observing the event `page_block_html_topmenu_gethtml_before` under the global area it will have no impact on the backend, because that event is not dispatched in the backend.
I choose this example, because in the `Mage_Catalog` module this exact event is observed under the `global` area. And this does not impact the frontend.
But because it's in the core, doesn't make it right.
As a general rule you should observe events only in the area you need it, because otherwise it **might** impact performance.

Comment: Yes, i know we need observer event where only in the area we need it . But i was wondering something more about whole magento event system  :D